# C# WCF self-hosted web service: publish serialization schema?

Tags: c#, wcf, devexpress, xml-serialization, self-hosting

I made a self-hosted web service in c# and everything works fine.

I work on this base Object class (DevExpress XPO):

```
[Persistent("System.StatusTable")]
public class XPStatusTable : XPBaseObject
{
    private short fIDTable;
    [Key(true)]
    public short IDTable
    {
        get { return fIDTable; }
        set { SetPropertyValue<short>("IDTable", ref fIDTable, value); }
    }

    private string fDescription;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return fDescription; }
        set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Description", ref fDescription, value); }
    }

    public XPStatusTable() { }
    public XPStatusTable(Session session) : base(session) { }
}
```

I serialize a collection of these objects:

```
    private string GetSerializedData()
    {
        StringWriter streamWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XPCollection<XPStatusTable>));
            XPCollection<XPStatusTable> list = new XPCollection<XPStatusTable>(uow);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, list);

            return streamWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The Service interface has got this function that return a string, but the string is a xml file with XPStatusTable schema..

```
    [OperationContract]
    string GetSerializedData();
```

Is there a way to publish in wsdl descriptor (or I don't know where) that 'GetSerializedData' return a collection of XPSatusTable instead a simple string?

Comment: can't you declare XPStatusTable  as a datacontract?

Comment: I try, but where I can find the data descriptor? In wsdl file? There isn't.. Consider that GetSerializedData() is the exposed method that return a string, not an array of XPStatusTable